# Autodesk Forge - Model Derivative API: Revit to .obj (Basics)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I know this might sound like a stupid question - but
I've seen on the [conversion table](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/) that .rvt files only have svf and thumbnail as derivative Formats. However i've seen posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577922/autodesk-forge-model-derivative-api-obj-files), where said conversion is apparently possible - while I'm getting an error.
Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the default SVF and thumbnail formats, you can also export the entire model or individual components to OBJ, as hinted at in the discussion on Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API: OBJ files:

[Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API: OBJ files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577922/autodesk-forge-model-derivative-api-obj-files)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeremy!
I've linked the same post - and found that it apparently IS possible despite the conversion table.
However I have yet to find any information on the HOW to do it (having a Revit file as a source)